# Issue after log in on Admin - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, admin-panel

After log in Magento Admin.

[image]

If I check this Totals.php line, this is what it contains >

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar
{
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('dashboard/totalbar.phtml');
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if (!Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Reports')) {
        return $this;
    }
    $isFilter = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('website') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('group');
    $period = $this->getRequest()->getParam('period', '24h');

    /* @var $collection Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
        ->addCreateAtPeriodFilter($period)
        ->calculateTotals($isFilter);

    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'));
    } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('website')){
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
    } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('group')){
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getGroup($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
    } elseif (!$collection->isLive()) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',
            array('eq' => Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_Store::ADMIN_CODE)->getId())
        );
    }

    $collection->load();

    $totals = $collection->getFirstItem();

    $this->addTotal($this->__('Revenue'), $totals->getRevenue());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Tax'), $totals->getTax());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Shipping'), $totals->getShipping());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Quantity'), $totals->getQuantity()*1, true);
}
}
```

This is the line with issues >
 ->addCreateAtPeriodFilter($period)

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Check if class **Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection** exists in the **app/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Mysql4/Order/Collection.php** and make sure that Classname is matching with the Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection

Comment: Hello! I have checked the path and it's > app/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Mysql4/Order/collection.php and this is the content > class Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
{
}